# Did people sing higher before?

Tags: voice

I have been listening to old recordings of sing-alongs. It wasnt too low for me as a tenor. Today many people sing too low for me. 
I am thinking of music from older movies.

I actually like this key. It works well for tenors.  It is not too low. It is often too low when I try to sing with people today. 
Did people sing higher before? And if so what was the reason for it?

Comment: At least in classical music the trend is towards higher and higher pitches, an effect called *pitch inflation*, see [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10388/2600), so I tend to answer no.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps I (and Cheddar) can be of assistance.

Essentially, this video covers how the invention of the microphone influenced the early 20th century music/recording industry and how it changed the music being produced, including the shift in popularity from tenors-only to more baritone/bass voices.

Namely, male singers had to sing higher to be recorded, but with the microphone, they didn't need to have high voices to be heard.

Comment: There are probably other reasons, including popular taste, but this is a cool chunk of info.